WebApplicationBuilder.Services.AddControllers causes FileNotFoundException
Using .NET 8 - my web app serves fine on debug, but when I publish it to a folder, it throws a FileNotFound exception.

Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

I have made sure I have the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen NuGet package installed.
Context:
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers(); // this line here

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseSession();

app.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

return app;

Edit: Jason Pan asked for the csproj file. Here it is

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <SpaRoot>..\prodschedule.client</SpaRoot>
    <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
    <SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:4200</SpaProxyServerUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy">
      <Version>8.*-*</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Server" Version="8.0.8">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.OpenApi" Version="1.6.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.7.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="6.7.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="6.7.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="6.7.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Sql\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\prodschedule.client\prodschedule.client.esproj">
      <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="W:\Improvement\Client Subscriptions\SubHashes\SubHashes.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="W:\Improvement\Libraries\CSharp\ApiLibrary\Holidays\Holidays.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="W:\Improvement\Libraries\CSharp\ApiLibrary\Http\Http.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="W:\Improvement\Libraries\CSharp\ApiLibrary\Ostendo\Ostendo.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="W:\Improvement\Libraries\CSharp\CSLogger\CSLogger.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="W:\Improvement\Libraries\CSharp\Utility\Utility.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


From your description, I know you are using .net8, but I still want to check what the version of your Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen, please share your .csproj file.

Please try to manually copy the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll file to the Publish Folder to see if there are other problems. If everything works well, you can consider including the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll file when publishing the project.

I thought this error had been throw just because of a middleware. Instead of calling AddController(), use AddControllerWithViews() middleware; it will resolve your issue.

For the next person who comes here from Google wanting to know what causes this.
It's Code Trimming. Disable code trimming and it'll work.
